# simple calculator in php with func_get_args

Tags: php

I have a simple calculator in php. And I am using the func_get_args for dynamically getting the values.

But the problem is with the multiply function.

So this is de code Calculator:

```
class Calculator
{
    protected $result;
    protected $operation;

    public function setOperation(OperatorInterface  $operation)
    {

        $this->operation = $operation;
    }

    public function calculate()
    {

        foreach (func_get_args() as $number) {
            $this->result = $this->operation->run($number, $this->result);
        }
    }

    public function getResult()
    {

        return $this->result;
    }
}
```

Multiply

```
class Multiply implements OperatorInterface{

    public function run($number, $result){

        return $result * $number;
    }
}
```

Index:

```
$sc = new Calculator();

$sc->setOperation(new Multiply);
$sc->calculate(10, 70);
echo $sc->getResult();
```

Because the result is 0. Because it starts with 0. But how to tackle this?

Thank you

interface:

```
interface OperatorInterface{
    public function run($number, $result);
}
```

If I do it like this:

```
class Multiply implements OperatorInterface{

    protected $result = 1;

    public function run($number, $result){    

        return var_dump($result * $number);
    }
}
```

and for exmample this:

```
$sc = new Calculator();

$sc->setOperation(new Multiply);
$sc->calculate(10, 70);
/* 
$sc->setOperation(new Adder());
$sc->calculate(100, 70);
$sc->setOperation(new Subtractor);
$sc -> calculate(500);
 */
echo $sc->getResult();
```

it is still 0.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that the `OperatorInterface` is **not** core PHP? A reference to it might be handy...

Comment: Each operation will need to start with an appropriate initial value - for multiplication, this will be the _"multiplicative identity"_ (i.e. the number for which multiplication results in no change) : **1**. For addition, you'd start with zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting 0 because `null * 10` give 0, after that you will get `0 * 70` which still results in 0.

Add the if statement to give a correct starting value:

```
class Multiply implements OperatorInterface{

    public function run($number, $result){
        
        if ($result === null) $result = 1;
        return $result * $number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate the calculator, result is 0. So you are multiplying `0 * $number` which is always 0. You could set result to 1 in your Multiply class:

```
class Multiply implements OperatorInterface{
    
    protected $result = 1;

    public function run($number, $result){

        return $result * $number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But it is still 0